# How do I calculate ratio in a full join using sql?

Tags: sql, case, outer-join

Suppose I have 2 tables (user profile table and website post table) shown below. I need to know the ratio of users (to total) that have posted within a month of their birthdays. How should I use sql to solve the question? Should I use a full join?

```
user_id birthday
12      8/12/1990
23      2/4/1967
34      3/15/1995

post_id user_id post_date
345     12      9/1/2021
768     12      8/23/2021
456     12      5/1/2021
567     34      8/21/2021
```

Comment: Thanks for editing for me!

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.